# Pagination controls in Django Rest Framework APIView

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I tried to add pagination to my custom view, and pagination works but i don't have this pagination controls to change pages like it is in default pagination styles, how I can add this controls to my view?

I was looking how to solve this problem but I hardly found anything, usuallly when I found some way to add pagination to custom view then it looks like this which I have, but it's not what I want because this doesn't give possibility to change page.

pagination.py

```
class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'limit': self.page_size,
            'result': data
        })
```

views.py

```
class TaskIndexAPIView(APIView):

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        for obj in list(self.filter_backends):
            queryset = obj().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
            return queryset

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'description', 'user__username')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        filtered_qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        tasks = filtered_qs
        for i in tasks:
            if i.date <= date.today() and i.status == 'NEW':
                i.delayed = 'This task is delayed'
                i.save()
            else:
                i.delayed = ''
                i.save()
        pagination_class = CustomPagination()
        page = pagination_class.paginate_queryset(tasks, request)
        serializer = IndexSerializer(page, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Have you considered using the default [paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/)? You might need to manipulate the response though.

Comment: I tried " return pagination_class.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)", and then pagination works but in exchange my search field dissapeard